# QGIS crashing when exporting very large image

Tags: qgis, raster, export, png

I'm trying to export a PNG of the OS 250k raster with OS Open Rivers over the top. Trying to export the entirety of the national grid caused it to crash, so I tried again with the bottom half of Great Britain and it's still crashing.

Here's the crash report:

> Crash ID: 1d5ed672dc1b64fc24118b59e560969ad8cbd8bb
>
> Stack Trace
>
> QVectorPath::convertToPainterPath :
> QVectorPath::convertToPainterPath :
> QVectorPath::convertToPainterPath :
> QVectorPath::convertToPainterPath :
> QRasterPaintEngine::fillRect :
> QRasterPaintEngine::drawImage :
> QgsRasterDrawer::drawImage qgsrasterdrawer.cpp:174
> QgsRasterDrawer::draw qgsrasterdrawer.cpp:105
> QgsRasterLayerRenderer::render qgsrasterlayerrenderer.cpp:274
> QgsMapRendererCustomPainterJob::doRender qgsmaprenderercustompainterjob.cpp:312
> QgsMapRendererCustomPainterJob::renderPrepared qgsmaprenderercustompainterjob.cpp:233
> QgsMapRendererTask::run qgsmaprenderertask.cpp:240
> QgsTask::start qgstaskmanager.cpp:78
> QThreadPoolPrivate::reset :
> QThread::start :
> BaseThreadInitThunk :
> RtlUserThreadStart :
>
> QGIS Info
> QGIS Version: 3.10.14-A Coru�a
> QGIS code revision: 8374282d2a
> Compiled against Qt: 5.11.2
> Running against Qt: 5.11.2
> Compiled against GDAL: 3.1.4
> Running against GDAL: 3.1.4
>
> System Info
> CPU Type: x86_64
> Kernel Type: winnt
> Kernel Version: 10.0.19042

The size of the image is 24000 * 20000 pixels at 1:250k resolution and 254 dpi (I found that 254 worked for a 16000 * 12000 file in terms of getting it to fit the canvas properly, but I don't know if it works for this size).

I have 32 GB of RAM, so should this work?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I'm no wiser from the error message.

However, the part of QGIS optimized for large-size output generation are layouts. I have not attempted to output an image of your size, but I routinely generate a 10240x7168 georeferenced tif file via `Layout / Export as image` or as part of an atlas. And I have had QGIS crash on me when accidentally trying to export an image with a 30000+- pixel dimension from the canvas, as the result of a typo on my side.

So I'd suggest setting up a very simple layout with the layers, dpi, and extent you want, no margins, and export that (georeferenced) and see if it helps.